# tensorflow Optimizer.minimize function

Tags: tensorflow, minimize

I am confused about minimize function.
Eg. a distance variable X with shape [mini_batch_size, 1],

```
loss_1 = tf.reduce_mean(X),

loss_2 = X
```

then minimize(loss_1) is mini-batch gradient descent,
but how about minimize(loss_2)? element-wise updating? If so, is it exactly the same as stochastic gradient descent?

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is a very technical thing in TF. loss_2 is.... equivalent to loss_1 up to the multiplication by the constant. It is not "SGD" as other answers suggest - this is not how TF works; it is also a mini batch update, and the only difference from loss_1 is that it is multiplied by batch_size, that's it.

The crucial element is hidden in a way tf.gradients is implemented. Namely, it expects **scalar** function to be passed as a first argument. However, if you pass multiple values it does not throw an error, instead **it just sums them**.  You can find this information in [official TF documentation of tf.gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients):

> ```
> gradients(
>     ys,
>     xs,
>     grad_ys=None,
>     name='gradients',
>     colocate_gradients_with_ops=False,
>     gate_gradients=False,
>     aggregation_method=None
> )
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Constructs symbolic partial derivatives of **sum of ys** w.r.t. x in xs.

So in fact your loss_2 is equivalent to:

```
equivalent_loss_2 = tf.reduce_sum(X)
```

and obviously the only difference from loss_1 is not dividing by batch_size. Nothing else.

```
x = tf.constant([[1.,2.,3.]]) # [3x1] , [batch_size x 1]

f = 2*x
f1 = tf.reduce_mean(f)
f2 = tf.reduce_sum(f)

g = tf.gradients(f, x)
g1 = tf.gradients(f1, x)
g2 = tf.gradients(f2, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(g))
    print(sess.run(g1))
    print(sess.run(g2))
```

Prints:

```
[[array([ 2.,  2.,  2.], dtype=float32)]]
[[array([ 0.66666669,  0.66666669,  0.66666669], dtype=float32)]]
[[array([ 2.,  2.,  2.], dtype=float32)]]
```

and as expected, g and g2 are the same, while g1 is just g (or g2) divided by 3 (batch_size)

Comment: Thanks lejlot for clarifying